# How can I tell if the libaries, dlls, and functions I use are C++ Native

Tags: c++, c, vb.net, dll

I am learning C++ with the intention to make programs with zero dependencies.

I am noticing that throughout my code I later find out that a libary/dll/functions I have been using requires the machine running it to have .NET installed or some other package.

How can I detect this beforehand?

Are most things that are possible with these .NET libaries/dlls/functions possible with only Native C++ libaries/dlls/functions?

I assumed so.

Comment: I would be interested to see how this has happened, but other than programming in C++/CLI or including many random libraries from the internet, this should not be happening for a beginner.

Comment: There are two completely different languages, C++ and C++/CLI. Could it be that you are learning from the wrong book (with the wrong language)?

Comment: The DLL could be written in a language that isn't C++.  Would that be considered?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I detect this beforehand?

Basically don't use anything beyond C++ standard library, which is described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

A tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can be handy.

You can also use static libraries to make program less dependent on DLLs.

> Are most things that are possible with these .NET
>   libaries/dlls/functions possible with only Native C++
>   libaries/dlls/functions?

The point is modern software must depend on some underlying framework and libraries, because it's pointless/impossible to write everything from scratch using only standard library. If you want to write rich application you need something like .NET. It can be cross-platform framework tho, like [qt](/questions/tagged/qt), which will give you more flexibility.